# Python, Selenium - can't locate a webpage element (button) with ID 'next'

Tags: python, selenium

I started learning python with selenium to automate some of my tasks. I have a problem which I'm unable to solve.
I'm trying to create a script which would automatically click the 'next' button.
I can't locate a webpage element (button) with ID 'next'. I tried every possible solution - by ID, by xpath etc.
It's possible that part of the webpage in which I'm trying to find the element is dynamically generated by jquery.
This is the error I get:

> Unable to locate element: [id="next"]

Here is what I've done until this point (fragments):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\technik 
informatyk\Desktop\python\geckodriver.exe')

browser.get('https://it-szkola.edu.pl/usr')
browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(3)

zgoda = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cookieLayerBoxButton"]')
zgoda.click()

browser.implicitly_wait(10) 
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('login-box-field-input')
emailElem.send_keys('mylogin')

passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
passwordElem.send_keys('mypassword')
passwordElem.submit()
time.sleep(2)
aktualnosci = browser.find_element_by_id('hBLAkt').click()
grandtest = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//* [@id="New178"]/div[2]/div[1]/p[2]/a').click()
lista = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Lista testów').click()
test = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]/a"))).click()

#browser.refresh()
#time.sleep(2)
nastepne = browser.find_element_by_id("next")

#nastepne = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Następne")))
#nastepne = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Następne').click()
nastepne.click()
```

Screenshots
[image: Code],

[image: Pic1],

[image: Pic2],

[image: Pic3],

[image: Pic4],

[image: Pic5]

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you upload the text of the HTML on your page rather than screenshots?  That would be helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: Please check if button is inside iframe element? When you press Run Test, test opens on new window?

Comment: @tomko [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: @Jdoe Are you sure that's the only element with `id='next'`. I have been bitted by something similar. Sometime some sites might have a similar structure repetead a bunch of times(javascript, css tricks, etc) for some reason, and you would find something but not what you are looking for. Have tried using xpath? Does it find it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Try xpath:
    `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="next"]')`

Try getting all buttons:

```
btns = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//button')
for btn in btns:
    txt = btn.text
    if txt == 'Następne':
         btn.click()
```